# How to access a c# script variable in a unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

so I want to save a string, int, etc variable in a c# script (c and c++ would be fine too) and then access that variable in a unity project. (I also want to do the opposite)

I currently know no way to make unity and the script read and write variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000341143-How-do-I-read-and-write-data-from-a-text-file-) from unity on how to read and write text files?

Comment: Yes, but that talks about how do access a text file that is in unity, But I want to access a file outside of unity in unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do.
You can't add C / C++ scripts to Unity (not that I'm aware of).
If you want, you can create a class by adding a C# script and saving it there, and access it by referencing to the class in other scripts, that's all really

Comment: Let me explain again, I want to have a variable in a c# script (I said c / c++ would be good to if I can access them) and then access that variable in a unity script. I think the class thing would work, I have to try that, thanks!